# Confidence interval for one-sample effect size: effect of uncertainty of variation?

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, effect-size, cohens-d

I have a one sample t-test (against null-hypothesis value 0) for which I would like to calculate the confidence interval on Cohen's d. I know the formula for Cohen's d (sample mean minus zero all divided by the sd). I know how to get the 95% CI for the mean, so I suppose I can plug the limits of this interval into that formula to get a CI for Cohen's d. But what nags at me is this: this isn't taking into account that as well as being uncertain about the population mean, I'm also uncertain about the sd. Is there a way to do this taking this into account? Should I take this into account?

Comment: The answer by Wolfgang is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as you rightly suspect, this approach does not take the uncertainty in the estimated SD into consideration (and use of the t-distribution is not sufficient to do so). In order to construct a CI that does take this into consideration, you have to make use of the non-central t-distribution and use an iterative procedure. See, for example, Cumming and Finch (2001) or Steiger and Fouladi (1997).

Basically, you just have to find those values of the non-centrality parameter of a non-central t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom that cut off .025 in the lower and upper tails of the distribution (assuming you want a 95% CI). Here is an example in R:

```
### data
x - c(0.7, 1.1, 0.5, 1.9, 1.1, 1.4, 0.5, 0.4, 1.2, 0.8, 
      -1.2, -1.0, 0.2, 0.4, -0.6, 0.4, -0.4, 0.7, -1.0, 2.4)

### does not take uncertainty in sd(x) into consideration
t.test(x)$conf.int / sd(x)
```

This yields:

```
[1] 0.03010098 0.96612980
```

And this is the correct approach:

```
tval <- t.test(x)$statistic
n <- length(x)
pt(tval, df=n-1, ncp=0.0266992 * sqrt(n), lower.tail=FALSE)
pt(tval, df=n-1, ncp=0.9579698 * sqrt(n), lower.tail=TRUE)
```

So, `0.0266992` and `0.9579698` are the CI bounds. I found those values by trial and error (starting with the values obtained above), but of course one could write a function that automates this.

Cumming, G., & Finch, S. (2001). A primer on the understanding, use, and calculation of confidence intervals that are based on central and noncentral distributions. *Educational and Psychological Measurement, 61*(4), 532-574.

Steiger, J. H., & Fouladi, R. T. (1997). Noncentrality interval estimation and the evaluation of statistical models. In L. L. Harlow, S. A. Mulaik, & J. H. Steiger (Eds.), *What if there were no significance tests?* (pp. 221-257). Mahwah, New Jersey: Erlbaum.

Answer (score 2):

That is why there are two formulas for the variance and standard deviation. In the description of a sample, the standard deviation is $s =\sqrt{ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \overline{x})^2}$ wheras, if you estimate the true standard deviation from the sample, the $\frac{1}{N}$ changes to $\frac{1}{N-1}$. Thus there is a ´correction´ in a way, as the estimated standard deviation and thus the 95%-CI is larger, if the sample gets smaller. For more on that search for "Bessel correction".

Comment: The correction means that the expected value of Cohen's d is unbiased but it may be too narrow because it isn't considering the uncertainty in the estimate of the standard deviation

Comment: That was useful information that I hadn't thought about, thanks @Bernhard. But I still don't feel it's entirely answering the question. The Bessel correction corrects bias in the central estimate of sd, so we know we have a good estimate of that, but we are still not taking into account our confidence around the estimate of the sd, which seems to me ought to influence our confidence around the estimate of the effect size. But I could be wrong and it seems from more information I have found that this is not typically taken into account.

Comment: In other words, what Hugh said...

Comment: @Amorphia I've been thinking about it a bit more. When we make a regular CI for the mean we can use the t-statistic to account for unknown variance, this makes CI which is wider than when using the z-statistic (1.96 for a 95% CI). I think that if you construct a 95% CI using the t-statistic for your sample size then this interval will account for the uncertainty in the variance.

Comment: OK that sounds interesting thanks @Hugh, I will look into that idea.